# Why am I not getting the correct percentage values in this T-SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following `T-SQL` query:

```
select 
     xx.[Market],
     xx.[RN],
     xx.[Total],
cast(CAST(((xx.[RN]/xx.[Total])) AS DECIMAL(19,2)) as varchar(10))+ ' ' + '%'  as [Percentage] 

from

(
select distinct Market, 
       sum(rn) over (partition by market) as [RN], 
       sum(rn) over () as [Total]

from [View1]
)xx
```

Output from above query is as follows:

```
 Market   RN    Total   Percentage
 UK       50     200     0.00 %
 France   25     200     0.00 %
 Germany  125    200     0.00 %
```

Why are the Percentages not showing correctly?

I am expecting the following output:

```
Market   RN    Total   Percentage
 UK       50     200     25.00 %
 France   25     200     12.50 %
 Germany  125    200     62.50 %
```

Comment: `INT / INT = INT`  so try `1.0*xx.[RN]/xx.[Total]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to explicitly make either the numerator or denominator of the percentage fraction a double type:

```
SELECT
    xx.[Market],
    xx.[RN],
    xx.[Total],
    CAST(CAST(1.0*xx.[RN] / xx.[Total] AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS varchar(10)) + ' ' + '%' AS [Percentage] 
--            ^^^ change here
FROM
(
     SELECT DISTINCT
         Market, 
         SUM(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY Market) AS [RN],
         SUM(rn) OVER () AS [Total]
    FROM [View1]
) xx;
```